# How can I increase the gap between loopcuts?

Tags: modeling

Using the "loopcut" function first, is there a way to widen the gap between the lines?

I think it's going to happen with "Scale". It's only increasing in volume. :.-(

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can indeed do what you want with Scale, you just need to lock the transformation to the X axis to prevent any transformation on the Y and Z axes. Press <kbd>S</kbd> followed immediately by <kbd>X</kbd> to lock the transformation to the X axis, and only the spacing between the edges will be modified.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Please don’t make edits changing “X axis” to “x-axis,” because [the former is what is used consistently throughout the Blender documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.92/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/control/axis_locking.html) and related material. Also, though the first sentence may technically be a comma splice, this sort of joining of conditionally related clauses is benign and common.

Answer (score 1):

1. enable symmetry in one axis. For example "X" axis
2. alt + select clicking on the loop to select the loop
3. Press the G + X to lock to X and only move in the X axis.

You can now resize the loops in the way you want.

[image]